# jQuery Button click not firing issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement a previous button on a test app. I cant get button id="prev" to fire. I am keeping it simple like this:

```
//Begin Previous Button Click Function
  //
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
      alert("i'm in previous button click");
  });
  // End of Previous Click Function
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alank90/geoevhke/16/)
I get nothing in the console and setting a break point in function does not  get called when stepping thru program. I checked the DOM to make sure btn2 was there and it is. Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element doesn't exist when the document is **ready**, because you inserted it **after** to the DOM.

Try with this instance:

```
$(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    // Call your prev button function or insert the code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

**As you are creating elements dynamically.** You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('#div2').on('click', '#prev', function(){ 
     //Your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will read up on event delegation and let you know how it turns out. Thanks to everyone for answering...

Comment: Reading up I have one question. I thought event handler was bound on first click. But now it seems it is on page load,yes?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem to make sense - if you want the item with id="prev" to fire, then your selector should be;

```
$("#prev")
```

not

```
$("#btn2")
```